# 2 default gateways for connection changeover?

Tags: linux, networking

I have a task to essentially change connections to our infrastructure (company's website) without downtime, and I have come up with a plan in my head that I think might work. So the basic setup is that all machines are on the same subnet (172.16.0.0/14) the old router and current default gateway for all machines is 172.16.1.1, and the new connection has been brought up as 172.18.1.1 (note, they are in the same subnet).

The idea was to assign a second default gateway to all the machines (all linux) temporarily pointing at the new router/connection, and then switch the DNS to point to the new public IPs on the new connection, and then wait until all connections are coming in there. Then get rid of the original default gateway that points to the old router/connection.

Does anyone think this could work? Or is there another way that I can accomplish this change-over without having to try and argue that we need some downtime for this? I don't really want to have to configure multiple routing tables on all these machines (there's about 100 of them) for this.

Comment: That definitely won't work. The computers would have no way to know which gateway was the "right" one, and if a connection went to the wrong gateway, it wouldn't be NATed correctly and thus wouldn't work.

Answer (score 1):

An option might be to set up a new machine, ServerA, that has both the gateways on it, one default, the other secondary.  Reconfigure all the other servers to route to ServerA, let it forward from there.  Then switch default gateway on ServerA.  All other servers will still go to ServerA, which will route through the correct network.  Then you can switch the others over slowly.  Might not completely remove downtime, but definitely reduce it.  When you are all done, then you can remove ServerA.

Answer (score 1):

If the public IPs are attached to the servers you can use [source policy routing](http://lartc.org/howto/lartc.rpdb.html#LARTC.RPDB.SIMPLE) to select the correct gateway for response packets. For example, if the old gateway 172.16.1.1 has public IPs 198.51.100.0/24, and the new gateway 172.16.1.2 has public IPs 203.0.113.0/24, configure the following on the servers:

```
echo 12 isp2 >> /etc/iproute2/rt_tables
ip route add default via 172.16.1.2 table isp2
ip rule add from 203.0.113.0/24 lookup isp2
```

This will route traffic using a new public IP via 172.16.1.2, while sending everything else (incoming and outgoing) via 172.16.1.1. The servers should now be accessible on the new public IPs, so you can switch the DNS entries. Once the old public IPs are no longer being used you can change the default route to 172.16.1.2 and remove the above configuration.

If the incoming connections are NATed to the servers you'll have to setup a new private subnet for the servers and configure the new gateway to NAT to this range instead.